# How to activate a scripting engine in activiti?

Tags: java, spring, osgi, activiti

I'm trying to run a short script in my workflow, this is a `taskListener` on a `userTask`:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener" >
  <activiti:field name="script" stringValue="${state='CREATED'}">
  </activiti:field>
  <activiti:field name="language" stringValue="JavaScript" />
</activiti:taskListener>
```

My environment seems to be missing a scripting engine though, this is the error I get:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Can't find scripting engine for 'JavaScript'
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.getEngineByName(ScriptingEngines.java:124)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.evaluate(ScriptingEngines.java:85)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.evaluate(ScriptingEngines.java:73)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.listener.ScriptTaskListener.notify(ScriptTaskListener.java:43)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.TaskListenerInvocation.invoke(TaskListenerInvocation.java:34)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.notify(ClassDelegate.java:121)
    ... 192 common frames omitted
```

Using the default engine `juel` also throws the same exception.
Activiti is running in an OSGi/Spring environment, using the following bundles:

- activiti-bpmn-converter-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-bpmn-model-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-cxf-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-engine-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-image-generator-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-process-validation-5.21.0.jar
- activiti-spring-5.21.0.jar

Maybe a bundle is missing?
This is the spring process engine configuration:

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
    <property name="history" value="full" />
</bean>
```

I might need to add another property `scriptingEngines` but what do I have to set as `value`? In my environment I don't have any class that extends `ScriptingEngines`.

Environment:
Java: jdk1.8.0_92 64-Bit
Spring: 4.2.5
Activiti: 5.21.0

Comment: What's you java version?

Comment: added environment to the post

Comment: I read a lot of solution for new Nashron javscript engine for java 8 (http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2014/04/24/running-activiti-on-jdk8/). Anyway I solved using groovy instead of javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Create a file `META-INF/javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory` 
in the bundle where the spring process engine configuration lays.

The following line, enables `juel` scripting:

```
org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.JuelScriptEngineFactory
```